# Saving mouse position to objects with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a world map and I want to have a posibility to mark 3 dots on map by left clicking on the map, and save positions of dots (x,y) to 3 objects.

[image]

I think that the best approach would be to create 3 objects of class Point, save position (x,y) of each dot to 3 objects of class Point. I did it only for one object (redPoint) because I'm not sure how I can do this for more objects.

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../resources/fxml/test.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("test");

    Point point = new Point();
    root.setOnMouseClicked(point::handle);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 720));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

```
public class Point {

private double x;
private double y;

public Point() {
}

public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    x = mouseEvent.getX();
    y = mouseEvent.getY();
    Point redPoint = new Point(x, y);
    System.out.println(redPoint.getX() + " " + redPoint.getY());
}
```

}

Current output:
"459.0 220.0" - x, y of place where I clicked but only for one dot and this dot is not placed on map

So I'm not sure:

- how to add colored dots in random place where I clicked
- how to save position of these dots to 3 different objects

Comment: solve one problem after the other .. (and only one per question): for each, first work through an appropriate tutorial, apply what you learned, when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected. BTW: your resource lookup is wrong - please read the java doc (to learn that dots are not supported!)

Answer (score 0):

Using JFX Canvas to display the map and the dot can be clicked as a little circle with color of course. Example

```
Canvas screen = new Canvas(580, 500);
gc = screen.getGraphicsContext2D();
screen.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
   double x = e.getX(), y = e.getY(); // the coordinates
   draw(x, y);
});
...
privat void draw(double x, double y) {
   ...
   gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   gc.setFill(Color.RED);
   gc.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);  // the dot
   ...
}
private GraphicsContext gc;
private Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("map.jpg"));
...
```

Hope that could help.